# Lubuntu Unable to Boot/Install

Tags: installation, boot, grub2, xubuntu, lubuntu

So I did something very stupid.

I was using Xubuntu.
I wanted to try Lubuntu so I installed the Lubuntu Desktop Flavor.

Thinking that I had installed the whole thing, I uninstalled Xubuntu. Through the command prompt.

I dont exactly know what I did as you can see I am a noob.

Now ofcourse it wont start.

I just see the lubuntu splash screen and then a bunch of error messages.

I have to use Live systems like TAILS and DSL now which are really not my cup of tea.

How do I fix it?

I have the LUBUNTU Live CD now.

But when I boot through it I end up in the grub recovery mode.

What do I do?

These are the error messages after the splash screen:

> *Stopping save Kernel messages [OK]
>   Speech-dispatcher disabled: edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
>       *Starting vnStat daemon vnstatd
>   *Starting the Winbind daemon winbind
>   *Starting NTP server ntpd
>   aned disabled: edit /etc/default/saned
>       *Checking battery state...
>   acpid: exiting
>   Checking for running unattended upgrades:
>   Shutting down SmartLink Modem Driver normally.
>   Unloading modem driver from kernel... none found.
>   *I2P Router daemon disabled in /etc/default/i2p.
>   speech dispatcher disabled:edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher.
>   *Stopping vnStat daemon vnstatd
>   *Asking all remaining processes to terminate....
>   *All processes ended within 1 seconds....
>   nm-dispatcher.action: Caught signal 15, shutting down...
>
> Deconfiguring  network interfaces...
>   Deactivating swap...
>   unmount: /run/lock: not mounted
>   unmount: /run/shm: not mounted
>   * will now halt
>   [    142.248586]

Comment: What happens if you press Shift during boot?

Comment: None of them are error messages (except for 1 which is certainly unrelated to your problem). They are standard, normal, expected informative (debugging) messages.

Comment: Umm...But the buntu still isnt loading. What do I do??

Answer (score 0):

You had to provide the errors verbatim, so we would have something to speak about. For now, I say you just should do a chroot into your system and reinstall lubuntu package again.

Comment: This is the error message after the splash screen

Comment: >*Stopping save Kernel messages [OK]
>Speech-dispatcher disabled: edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
>    *Starting vnStat daemon vnstatd
>*Starting the Winbind daemon winbind
>*Starting NTP server ntpd
>aned disabled: edit /etc/default/saned
>    *Checking battery state...

Comment: The following error messages are received when power button in the Laptop is pressed.